# Take one table as input and output using another table BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have one table and want to use it as my input for a query pulling from another table:

input table:

```
   +----------+--------+
    |   item   | period |
    +----------+--------+
    | HD.4TB   |      6 |
    | 12333445 |      7 |
    | 12344433 |      5 |
    +----------+--------+
```

And I'm using this query to use the input:

```
SELECT 
snapshot, 
item_name,  
commodity_code,
planning_category, 
type, 
SUM(quantity) qty, 
sdm_month_start_date,
FROM planning_extract 
WHERE 
planning_category IN (SELECT item FROM input) 
GROUP BY snapshot, 
item_name,  
commodity_code,
planning_category, 
type, 
sdm_month_start_date
```

The issue is in the input table, if it's string, then it should be planning_category; if it's number, then it's item_name. what I think something could make sense is to change "where" clause above:

```
WHERE (planning_category or item_name) IN (SELECT item FROM input)
```

But this gives me error says "Semijoin expression (i.e. "x IN (SELECT ...)") must be a part of logical AND."

So is there any way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: `WHERE (planning_category IN (SELECT item FROM input) OR item_name IN (SELECT item FROM input) )` ?

Answer (score 1):

These are all equivalent:

1.

```
SELECT word, corpus FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare] 
WHERE (word OR corpus) IN (SELECT x FROM (SELECT 'hamlet' x), (SELECT 'about' x))
```

2.

```
SELECT word, corpus FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare] 
WHERE word IN (SELECT x FROM (SELECT 'hamlet' x), (SELECT 'about' x))
OR corpus IN (SELECT x FROM (SELECT 'hamlet' x), (SELECT 'about' x))
```

3.

```
SELECT word, corpus
FROM (
  SELECT word, corpus FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare] 
  WHERE word IN (SELECT x FROM (SELECT 'hamlet' x), (SELECT 'about' x))
), (
  SELECT word, corpus FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare] 
  WHERE corpus IN (SELECT x FROM (SELECT 'hamlet' x), (SELECT 'about' x))
)
```

The 3rd one works in BigQuery - but might produce some duplicates.

To prevent duplicates (1 row in this case):

```
SELECT word, corpus
FROM (
  SELECT word, corpus FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare] 
  WHERE word IN (SELECT x FROM (SELECT 'hamlet' x), (SELECT 'about' x))
), (
  SELECT word, corpus FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare] 
  WHERE corpus IN (SELECT x FROM (SELECT 'hamlet' x), (SELECT 'about' x))
  AND word NOT IN (SELECT x FROM (SELECT 'hamlet' x), (SELECT 'about' x))
)
```

(replace (SELECT 'hamlet' x), (SELECT 'about' x) with your favorite table)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be a SQL problem, not a bigquery one. As [Turophile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2427560/turophile) pointed out in his comment, the correct syntax should be

```
WHERE (planning_category IN (SELECT item FROM input) OR item_name IN (SELECT item FROM input) )
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe Google is not letting us use `IN` in `OR`s, only in `AND`s. That's really awful, I'm facing the same problem.

The solution

```
WHERE (planning_category IN (SELECT item FROM input) OR item_name IN (SELECT item FROM input) )
```

will **not** solve the problem, and you'll get the same error `Semijoin expression (i.e. "x IN (SELECT ...)") must be a part of logical AND.`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @DavidPostill I had an answer there, just placed it after the warning. Now I put the answer first