# How can I use an input from another table in my query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm creating a new table using PostgreSQL, but I need to get a parameter from another table as an input.

This is the table I have (I called table_1):

```
id    column_1
1     100
2     100
3     100
4     100
5     100
```

I want to create a new table, but only using ids that are higher than the highest id from the table above (table_1). Something like this:

```
insert into table_new
select id, column_1 from  table_old 
where id > (max(id) from table_1)
```

How can I do this? I tried searching, but I got to several posts like https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/M-Query-Create-a-table-using-input-from-another-table/td-p/209923, [Take one table as input and output using another table BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27932717/take-one-table-as-input-and-output-using-another-table-bigquery) and [sql query needs input from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43166884/sql-query-needs-input-from-another-table), which are not exactly what I need.

Comment: `where id > (select max(id) from table_1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `where id > (select max(id) from table_1)`.

Comment: Wow, so easy... I tried this once before, but it didn't work. Must have done something wrong, thank you!